# How can I get rid of this image at bottom of page?

Tags: html, css

There's an img element being created somehow on this page that I can't figure out how to target. It's generated by a script I don't have access to so I can't just delete it.

There are no ID or class attributed to it so I can't apply CSS (that I know of). The source link also changes for other article pages so I can't reference the URL either.

Is there anyway I can target or just hide it? It's creating extra white space at the bottom of the page.

http://support.spacejump.co.nz/support/solutions/articles/27000068245-payment-methods

[image: White Psace]

Comment: You could delete that img element and remove the space.

Comment: Apologies I forgot to mention, the IMG is generated by a script which I cannot figure out/don't have access to prevent occurring. I can't delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways depending upon the possibilities on your website.

1: I suppose there will be no `img` tag directly inside the `body` tag if you code properly and put it inside a `div` or any other tag. So, for this solution is:

`body > img {display: none;}`

2: If first is not the case and the image will always come after the `script` tag. Then this also is the solution:

`body > script + img {display: none;}`

BTW, both are working in your situation.

Comment: Thanks for that solution. I used the first one. I was not aware of the > selector so thank you for enlightening me!

Comment: Happy to help @dpnz

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the page and view source. You can see the element present int the page source. Delete it in the source code in line 551.

Comment: Apologies I forgot to mention, the IMG is generated by a script which I cannot figure out/don't have access to prevent occurring. I can't delete it.

Answer (score 0):

If the image `src` attribute is guaranteed to be consistent over time, then you can target it by that attribute, and remove it.

```
document
  .querySelector('img[src="/support/solutions/articles/27000068245-payment-methods/hit"]')
  .remove()
```

Comment: The src attribute changes for each page, so I don't believe I can do that.

Comment: Can't you do what [Bonlou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8764888/bonlou) mentioned by substituting the src value for all the different attribute change?

Comment: If I understand correctly, and I might not, this doesn't seem like an effective solution because of how many articles with unique src URLS there are, and every time we create a new article we'd have to add it. 

What i'm looking for is something in CSS like lastchild that allows me to target the very last img on the page. This is the last IMG that occurs within the body. Is there not something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a JS solution to target the last class in the page before all those JS src CDNs... As it seems the IMG tag is after a bunch of JS tags with the very last element in your page being the `layout` class, so we create a helper function that gets the siblings of the target element, then we loop over the array returned by the function and set an index, then check the `tag.tagName === 'IMG'` and check our iterated index => `i` is higher than the set index, if we get a match, remove that element from the DOM.

```js
const removeImg = document.querySelector('.layout')
const body = document.body

function getAllSiblings(element, parent) {
  const children = [...parent.children];
  return children.filter(child => child !== element);
}

function removeImageAfterElement(el) {
  let index = 0;
  getAllSiblings(removeImg, body).forEach((tag, i) => {
    tag.classList.contains(el) ? index = i : null
    tag.tagName === "IMG" && i > index ? tag.remove() : null
  })
}

removeImageAfterElement(removeImg)
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="another-class"></div>
  <div class="layout layout--anonymous">
    some text and page content
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.2.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/package@version/file"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@freshworks/freshdesk/dist/freshdesk.js"></script>
  <script></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"></script>
  <img src="/support/solutions/articles/27.............../hit">
</body>
```